# Android/Java and multiple "view states"

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

Does anyone recognize this pattern and know of a tidy solution?

I've got a view that can be in certain states. Let's call them `Neutral`, `Success`, `Error`, `InProgress`. In the view I've got multiple elements (Buttons, TextViews and a ProgressBar) that should either be visible/enabled depending on the state the view is in.

Currently I've got methods that represent the states that do the necessary `.setEnabled()` and `.setVisibility()` calls. With 4 states and a couple of elements this becomes messy quite fast.

I also feel that the [State Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) is not necessarily a good solution but is something that personally springs to mind.

I would love to hear what any of you think is a simple and tidy solution.

Sample code:

```
void setIsRegistering() {
    isRegistering = true;
    isRegistered = false;

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    successText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    errorText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    setupFooterButton.setEnabled(false);
    setupFooterButton.setText("Adding browser");
}

void setIsRegistered() {
    isRegistering = false;
    isRegistered = true;

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    successText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    errorText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    setupFooterButton.setEnabled(true);
    setupFooterButton.setText("Next");
}

void setIsNotRegistered() {
    isRegistering = false;
    isRegistered = false;

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    successText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    errorText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    setupFooterButton.setEnabled(true);
    setupFooterButton.setText("Add browser");
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ViewAnimator for this: (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html)

You can then call viewAnimator.setDisplayedChild() to set the selected item.

setDisplayedChild() takes an integer, so I typically create an enum to hold the states I want:

```
enum ViewStates {
   NEUTRAL, SUCCESS, ERROR
}


setDisplayedChild(ViewStates.Neutral.ordinal());
```

Or if that's too verbose:

```
enum ViewStates {
   NEUTRAL, SUCCESS, ERROR

   public static int neutral = NEUTRAL.ordinal();
   public static int success = SUCCESS.ordinal();
   public static int error = ERROR.ordinal();
}

setDisplayedChild(neutral);
```

Comment: Doesn't this only handle one child? Where would I specify which elements should be visible or not? I don't think this is the solution I'm looking for, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: In your example, I see three states: one that shows a progress bar, one that shows a success textbox, and one that shows an error textbox. If that's all there is to it, I don't see why a ViewAnimator won't do what you want.

However, if you have for instance 100 elements, and 50 different states, each of which represents any number of various visibility configurations of the 100 elements (going with an extreme example), obviously ViewAnimator is not what you want. But based on how I read your question, it seemed like it might be a fit.